# Sencha Touch: Clicking a button rapidly will push a view twice

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Say I have a button that triggers a push of a new view.
I noticed that if I click it more than once, fast enough, it will push the same view twice.

You can mimic this behavior using their official docs on this page, where they have a live sample:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/navigation_view

the clear question is, simply how to prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the button during the push function?

Comment: @Alex: sure I could play with solutions like these, although I imagine there should be a more elegant standardized way to work with Sencha.

Comment: Yeah, quite possible. I've googled some though and the general consense was to disable the button or implement a timer logic. Choose whatever's more pragmatic imo.

Comment: since their own docs sink has the issue - i dont think so but its quite normal for us, having to avoid jittering events. Use a timeout or 'disable -> push -> enable' as Alex said

Comment: I had a feeling this would be the only solution... unless something better comes up, I accept this answer. thanks.

Comment: So, pushing a button twice causes its event handler to fire twice, and this is a problem for you?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan A problem for the user, who might end up with duplicate pushed views (having to press "back" button twice to actually go back, just because he somehow managed to accidentally hit the button during the animation to the pushed view), which is eventually a problem for the developer, so yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Masking successfully prevents double tapping problem.

In my code I'm using two functions for mask/unmask navigation container:

```
/**
 * Mask container with rolling wheel. Usually need if Ajax-request is sent to the server and app waiting for response
 * Best practice is masking the current navigator container, to prevent blocking whole app. Method warns if no container
     * is defined. In some cases warning could be suppress with parameter
     *
     * @param container
     * @param {boolean} [suppressWarning]
     */
    startLoading: function(container, suppressWarning) {
        var loadingComponent = container;

        if (!loadingComponent) {
            // <debug>
            if (!suppressWarning) {
                console.warn('Please define navigator container for non-blocking operation, or define suppressWarning parameter');
            }
            // </debug>
            loadingComponent = Ext.Viewport;
        }

//      var lastMaskedContainer = container;
        this.lastMaskedContainer = container;

        loadingComponent.setMasked({
            xtype: 'loadmask',
            message: 'Loading...'
        });

/*
        Ext.defer(function() {
            lastMaskedContainer.setMasked(false);
        }, Pipedrive.app.maskingTimeout * 1000)
*/
    },

    /**
     *
     * @param {Ext.Container} container
     * @param {boolean} [suppressWarning]
     */
    stopLoading: function(container, suppressWarning) {
        var loadingComponent = container;

        if (!loadingComponent) {
            // <debug>
            if (!suppressWarning) {
                console.warn('Please define either navigator container for non-blocking operation, or define suppressWarning parameter');
            }
            // </debug>
            loadingComponent = Ext.Viewport;
        }

        var alreadyMasked = loadingComponent.getMasked();

        var lastMaskedContainer = this.lastMaskedContainer;
        if (!alreadyMasked && !suppressWarning) {
            // <debug>
            if (lastMaskedContainer != container) {
                console.warn('Found Start/Stop Loading inconsistency. Please revise code'
                    + (container ? '. Container: ' + container.getId() : 'Ext.Viewport')
                    + (lastMaskedContainer ? ', last masked container: ' + lastMaskedContainer.getId() : '')
                );
            }
            // </debug>
            loadingComponent = Ext.Viewport;
        }
        loadingComponent.setMasked(false);
    }
```

than in the tap handler:

```
onDealDetailsTap: function(ct) {
    console.log('onDealDetailsTap', ct);
    var form = ct.getReferenceForm(),
        navigatorContainer = this.getNavigatorContainer(form),
        model = form.getRecord();

    UiHelper.startLoading(navigatorContainer);
    Ext.Viewport.fireEvent('detailfields', {
        title: model.get('title'),
        id: model.get('id'),
        store: 'DealFields',
        navigatorContainer: navigatorContainer
    })
},
```

to cleanup the loading mask:

```
control : {
    activitiesContainer: {
        push: 'onPushActivitiesContainer'
    },




onPushActivitiesContainer: function(ct) {
    //console.log('onPushActivitiesContainer', ct);
    UiHelper.stopLoading(ct);
},
```

especially it is cool for waiting for long-timed ajax requests....

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Great answer, without having to disable each 'tap' listener individually. Thank you.

Comment: Can someone help? I tried pushing the next view, then popping it, and when I try to push a new view I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null ` . Also, I am not sure about the fireEvent method, so I did this instead: `me.getNavigationView().push(view);`

Answer (score 8):

Another method is to check what the active view is, and only push if it is not the same as the view you are about to push. I've tested this and it works.

E.g.

```
if (this.getNavigationView().getActiveItem().xtype != "someView") {
    this.getNavigationView().push({ xtype: "someView" });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Extending jayteejee's answer, I've overridden the push method in a custom navigation view, like this:

```
Ext.define('BT.navigation.View', {
   extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
   xtype: 'btnavigationview',

   push: function (view) {
      if(this.getActiveItem().xtype != view.xtype)
         this.callParent(arguments);
      else
         console.warn("Prevented pushing a potentially duplicate view of xtype: " + view.xtype);
   }
});
```

I'm not totally sure if the `xtype` assumption is safe enough, but I can't think of any situation in my current app that would require one view pushing another view of the same type onto the navigation stack. So, the solution works for me, and it's pretty neat. The warning is there to save me headache later on and possibly pulling my hair out trying to work out why `push` wouldn't work!

Comment: Really neat solution. I changed your if statement a little though: `if (typeof this.getActiveItem() == 'undefined' || this.getActiveItem().xtype != view.xtype)` in case there is no active item set yet.

Comment: You should add a `view.destroy();` to the else block. Otherwise the view instance will stay in memory and slowly slow down the app.

Answer (score 2):

Just suspend the events on the button when it's tapped and resume them when the view is pushed

```
button.suspendEvents();
...
button.resumeEvents();
```

I don't think there is another way. As a developer or a user, when you tap a button twice, you expect the event handler to be called twice.

Hope this helps

Comment: Generally this is what you expect. in this case the user is not supposed to be able to push the button again during a transition to a new screen (view). that's how it works with android activities, iOS navigation controller etc..

Answer (score 2):

simply mask the entire container and then unmask it; create a ref for the container or panel in which the button exists in your controller and on tap set:

```
ref.setMasked(true)
```

After the new view is pushed simply unmask by

```
ref.setMasked(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to flip a parameter once the list item has been tapped once, like this:

```
{
   onListItemTap: function () {
      if (!this.tapped) {
         this.tapped = true;
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Of course, that only works if you are destroying the list view as soon as the user goes to a different screen.

Answer (score 0):

I created a method for checking this:

```
    ENSURE_NO_DOUBLE_TAP : function(classNameToPush) {
        if (Ext.getClassName(Ext.getCmp('MyViewport').getActiveItem()) == classNameToPush) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Then from your app before anything that could be double tapped is processed:

```
        if (!ENSURE_NO_DOUBLE_TAP('MyApp.view.View')) {
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are listening to the tap event of a button using listeners,then here is 
my solution:

```
listeners : {   
     release : function(){                                  
          if(this.getDisabled())return false;
          this.setDisabled(true);
          this.fireEvent('tap');
     },
     tap : function() {
         //do what you want
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on jayteejee's and Merott's answers, I've added some code to intercept on multiple fast pushes to not only prevent duplicates but to prevent pushing of different views as well before the page transition completes. Think of a user tapping different list items.

Also notice the `view.destroy();` method in the else block to prevent view instances from heaping up in memory.

```
Ext.define('Overrides.navigation.View', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'ovrnavigationview',

    interceptPush: false,

    push: function (view) {
        var activeItem = this.getActiveItem();

        // Prevent multiple pushes & duplicates
        if (!this.interceptPush && activeItem.xtype !== view.xtype) {

            // Set interceptPush
            this.interceptPush = true;

            // Reset interceptPush after 500 ms
            Ext.defer(function() {
                this.interceptPush = false;
            }, 500, this);

            // Handle push
            this.callParent(arguments);

        } else {

            // Warn developer
            console.warn("Prevented pushing view of xtype: " + view.xtype);

            // Destroy view
            view.destroy();

            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the "itemsingletap" event.

If you want to support double taps as well, make a second listener for "itemdoubletap" and invoke the same function, both listeners work fine together.