# Difference between Class.override() vs Ext.define('Class', override: 'Class' ... to create an override

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

**What's the difference between these 2 override**

So option 1:

```
Ext.window.Window.override({
    initComponent: function () {
        this.draggable = false;
        this.resizable = false;

        this.on('resize', function () {
            this.center();
        });

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

option 2:

```
Ext.define('Ext.window.WindowOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.window.Window',

    initComponent: function () {
        this.draggable = false;
        this.resizable = false;

        this.on('resize', function () {
            this.center();
        });

        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

**Which approach should I follow and why?**

*Specifically using Extjs 4.1.1*

Comment: You might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254321/best-practice-for-overriding-classes-properties-in-extjs

Comment: this should not be marked as duplicate anymore in my opinion

Comment: This is not a duplicate, and the answer referenced at the top does not provide best practice advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second option is basically a wrapper for the first one; it will apply overrides after `Ext.window.Window` has been loaded.

Calling `Class.override()` is a relic of Ext JS 3.x days, when there was no dynamic class loading available and you had to take care of the plumbing yourself. There is no reason to use it with 4+.