# Why the ext component is not overriden although I did exactly as written in documentation?

Tags: extjs, overriding

I would like to override Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel so that instead of text ‘Search’ some other text appears, for example ‘xyz’.

I have a LiveSearchGridPanel as:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.List', {
    //extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    extend: 'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel',
    xtype: 'mainlist',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.store.Personnel'
    ],

    title: 'Personnel',

    store: {
        type: 'personnel'
    },

    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', flex: 1 }
    ],

    listeners: {
        select: 'onItemSelected',
        afterrender: function() {
            console.log('We have been rendered');
        }
    }
});
```

I created new file LiveSearchGridPanel123.js in ${app.dir}/overrides directory:

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.LiveSearchGridPanel123', {
    override: 'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel',

   initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
       console.log(this.self.getName() + ' created 123');
        me.tbar = ['XXX', {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'searchField',
                hideLabel: true,
                width: 20,
                listeners: {
                    change: {
                        fn: me.onTextFieldChange,
                        scope: this,
                        buffer: 100
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: '<',
                tooltip: 'Find Previous Row',
                handler: me.onPreviousClick,
                scope: me
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: '>',
                tooltip: 'Find Next Row',
                handler: me.onNextClick,
                scope: me
            }
        ];

        me.bbar = Ext.create('Ext.ux.StatusBar', {
            defaultText: me.defaultStatusText,
            name: 'searchStatusBar'
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And I added

```
    requires: [
        'Ext.overrides.LiveSearchGridPanel123',
   ],
```

In app.js.

Then I did sencha app refresh, but component remained the same.
Could you please tell me where the the error is?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrRuG.png)

Comment: After making a change like override or extending one of my own classes I like to remove the build directory and also bootstrap.*  in the app director and then build again, as opposed to doing a app refresh.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14254627/1068246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you call parent `this.callParent();`.

You can try:

```
Ext.define(null,{
    override:'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel',
    initComponent: function() {
        const me = this;
        me.tbar = [{
            xtype:'textfield'
        }];
       this.superclass.superclass.initComponent.call(this); //<-- this does the magic
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel. How can I further override it to include x button in this 'textfield' to clear its vaule? I've tried to use xtype: 'searchfield', but I got an error.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ard i think, this will work. But i suggest you make your own livesearchgrid with ViewController without override Ext version.